# Using lxml to process html from requests. TypeError: can't pickle _ElementUnicodeResult objects

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, python-requests

I am trying to get data found at a specific xpath on a page. I am able to get to the page via requests. I have verified I am at the correct page by using r.text to print the source code to my screen and comparing the displayed text to the text I am looking for.

r.text returns a string that is difficult to extract the info I want out of. I have been informed lxml is the way to go in order to search for info by xpath. Unfortunately, I am getting a type error.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

payload = {'login_pass': 'password', 'login_user': 'username','submit':'go'}
r = requests.get("website", params=payload)

print r.encoding
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
print tree
print tree.text_content()
```

returns

```
UTF-8
<Element html at 0x10dab8d08>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Me/Documents/PYTHON/GetImageAsPdf/ImageToPDF_requests_beta.py", line 11, in <module>
    print tree.text_content()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1343, in write
    return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/rpc.py", line 595, in __call__
    value = self.sockio.remotecall(self.oid, self.name, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/rpc.py", line 210, in remotecall
    seq = self.asynccall(oid, methodname, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/rpc.py", line 225, in asynccall
    self.putmessage((seq, request))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/rpc.py", line 324, in putmessage
    s = pickle.dumps(message)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle _ElementUnicodeResult objects
```

I tried checking the headers

```
r.headers
```

returns

```
{'charset': 'utf-8',
 'x-powered-by': 'PHP/5.3.3',
 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
 'set-cookie': 'PHPSESSID=c6i7kph59nl9ocdlkckmjavas1; path=/, LOGIN_USER=deleted; expires=Tue, 15-Oct-2013 15:12:08 GMT; path=/',
 'expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT',
 'server': 'Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)',
 'connection': 'close',
 'pragma': 'no-cache',
 'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
 'date': 'Wed, 15 Oct 2014 15:12:09 GMT',
 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}
```

My goal is to be able to search the tree via xpath like this:

```
quantity = tree.xpath('/html/body/form[1]/table[3]/tbody[1]/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/strong')
```

Can you please help me identify where I am going wrong?

Comment: Where are you running this code from? IDLE?

Comment: yes I am using IDLE. Python 2.7.6. Mac OSx 10.8.5.

I am using the IDLE that came built in with python when installed with homebrew.

Comment: It looks like that error is happening because IDLE needs to pickle the contents of the command you're trying to run and send it to another process. If you run this script directly from the CLI, does it work ok?

Comment: yep. That seems to have done the trick. My goal of using that quantity line is not picking up any data by that xpath, but I suppose that is another issue all together. The tree is no longer returning an error so I am one step closer to success. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to convert the `_ElementUnicodeResult` object into a regular, picklable unicode string.

With Python 2, simply wrap it with `unicode()`, e.g. `print unicode(tree.text_content())`

And with Python 3, simply wrap it in `str()`, e.g. `str(tree.text_content())`